# Image src on index.html gets distorted with react router path?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a two images on my index.html file that behaves like a loading page for my react app.

On my app.js I have the following routes rendering:

```js
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
          <Route path="/contactus" exact component={ContactForm}/>
          <Route path="/shop" exact component={shopLanding}/>

          <Route path="/product-page/:slug/:idNumber" exact component={ShopPages}/>)

      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

For the first 3 routes the images src on the index.html file get called as: 
`http://localhost:3000/images/LoadingPageBackground.jpg` and `http://localhost:3000/images/purpleHandsLogo.png`

On the last routes the images give a 404 error an are called as such:

`GET http://localhost:3000/product-page/straight/images/purpleHandsLogo.png 404 (Not Found)`

`GET http://localhost:3000/product-page/straight/images/LoadingPageBackground.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Along with another error:

`GET http://localhost:3000/product-page/straight/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

This new url is being called from the `<Link>` path coming from another component that links to the last route shown above. The `<Link>` looks like this:

```js
<Link to={{ pathname: `/product-page/${this.props.slug}/${this.props.idNumber}`,
                  state: {
                    urlId: this.props.idNumber
                  }
                }}>
```

I can fix this issue by making the image link on index.html start with `http://localhost:3000/` instead of a file path but this will no longer work once the site is live.

Why is the image src's being changed for this particular route?

Any help?

Comment: you need to start your path names with `/` to have them load from the root. '/images/logo.png' will load from the images folder, 'images/logo.png' will load from the relative path of the file requesting the images.

Comment: Awesome thank you! @mattdevio. Do you have an understanding as to why I get this error and where it could be coming from `GET http://localhost:3000/product-page/straight/undefined 404 (Not Found)` I'm not requesting it anywhere but its similar to the images error?

Comment: Most likely has to do with the historyApiFallback on a hard refresh.